# How can a filter combine the result of another filter with Logical AND?

Tags: filter, widget, typo3, extbase, fluid

I have 2 filters. One filter gets the result of the other filter:

```
<example:widget.myfilter objects="{blogs}" as="filteredblogs" property="features.uid">
    <example:widget.anotherfilter objects="{filteredblogs}" as="filteredmoreblogs" property="test.name">
```

Filter 1 has one "like" Query.
Filter 2 has one "in" Query.

Filter 1 Controller

```
public function indexAction(string $filterfeatures = ""): void
{
    $feature = $this->featureRepository->getFeatureByName($filterfeatures);
    $query = $this->objects->getQuery();
    if(count($feature) > 0) {
        $query->matching($query->in($this->property, $feature));
    }
    $modifiedObjects = $query->execute();
    
    $this->view->assign('contentArguments', [
        $this->as => $modifiedObjects
    ]);
```

Filter 2 Controller:

```
public function indexAction(string $filtertest = ""): void
    {
        $query = $this->objects->getQuery();
        $query->matching($query->like($this->property, $filtertest));
        $modifiedObjects = $query->execute();
        $this->view->assign('contentArguments', [
            $this->as => $modifiedObjects
        ]);
```

My problem is that both make a query, but ignore each other. The 2nd filter overwrites the 1st filter.

It would need a logical AND between the 2 filters.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though this might not be the answer you want to here but: Don't use widgets!

In TYPO3 11 all widgets have been removed from TYPO3, checkout the docs about this important change: https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/master/en-us/Changelog/master/Breaking-92529-AllFluidWidgetFunctionalityRemoved.html

---

As a solution I suggest you move the logic back into your main controller and solve it here. I prefer using a simple PHP object for the configuration of such filters. You can take a look at https://github.com/FriendsOfTYPO3/tt_address/blob/master/Classes/Controller/AddressController.php#L67-L78

Comment: I never thought about that. I learned in a book that filters are implemented with widgets. Thanks for this idea. I've rebuilt it now and it works great.